# Counter Strike 1.6 - trouble with Intel Integrated GPU graphics

Tags: performance, counter-strike

I have a laptop with Intel integrated GPU graphics, and I can't squeeze 100 fps out of this card in D3D mode, while the game hangs periodically when using OpenGL.

The graphics are worse in D3D. Given that OpenGL is a better opensource graphics library, shouldn't it perform better then something devised by Microsoft?

What can I do to help this? Would upgrading to a i5/i7 processor with Intel HD Graphics solve this issue? Do I really need a dedicated graphics card?

Comment: Do you mean Counter-Strike 1.6 or Counter-Strike: Source?  1.6 is quite a few years old, and I'm amazed that you'd have any issues running it.

Comment: cs source runs fine...i have problems with cs 1.6 ......I have heard that a minimal old graphics card with much less capabilities run this game much better with 99 fps, but installing a gfx card is not an option in my comp

Comment: Interesting.  Is there any reason you are so determined to use OpenGL?  If you're getting 50+ frames in d3d, it seems like using that is your best bet.

Comment: well with the level of gaming i am involved in...the details (people sitting in dark corners, or far away and get mixed with textures) should be clearly visible.

Comment: Hold out for Intel's new CPU's, their integrated GPUs blow all the current inventory out of the water

Comment: How big of an handicap is it to not reach 100 fps in CS? It should still be more than your monitor is able to actually display.

Comment: What FPS do you get using OpenGL? Are you sure that there is no frame limiter?

Answer (score 1):

- In your Intel Integrated GPU Settings, turn off VSync
- Once you start the game, alt-tab onto the Desktop and back. Do that couple of times and you'll be able to achieve 100 fps

Comment: Hi, Anil, and welcome to Arqade! Do you have a source for this answer?  It seems like a very odd procedure for improving video performance, so it'd be nice to have another site as verification.

Comment: I've been playing CS 1.6 for years. This is how I increase my FPS when I go for tournaments where systems with bad spec are given. Dont have a site to back my observation. But it works.You can take my word for it